# Gridview Event not Firing in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the below code where I am trying to programatically create an event handler and it runs without an error but when I click on one of the buttons in the row, the event isn't being fired. Any input would be helpful.

```
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int T = 0; T <= 26; T++)
        {
            Label x = new Label();
            x.ID = T.ToString();
            x.Text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit id felis ac volutpat. Aenean tempor faucibus est, ac feugiat libero egestas sit amet. Aliquam";

            Label y = new Label();
            y.ID = "Title_" + T.ToString();
            y.Text = "Title " + T.ToString();



            RadioButton Radio1 = new RadioButton();
            Radio1.ID = "R_" + T.ToString();
            Radio1.Text = "Yes";
            Radio1.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
            Radio1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
            Radio1.AutoPostBack = true;

            RadioButton Radio2 = new RadioButton();
            Radio2.ID = "RX_" + T.ToString();
            Radio2.Text = "No";
            Radio2.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
            Radio2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
            Radio2.AutoPostBack = true;

            Panel StatusBar = new Panel();

            StatusBar.ID = "status_" + T.ToString();


            PlaceHolder pcl = new PlaceHolder();
            pcl.ID = "test_" + T.ToString();
            pcl.Controls.Add(y);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            pcl.Controls.Add(x);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            pcl.Controls.Add(Radio1);
            pcl.Controls.Add(Radio2);
            pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>..."));
            form1.Controls.Add(pcl);
            form1.Controls.Add(StatusBar);
        }

        //form1.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder { ID = "MyStatusBar" });
    }
    protected void test1()
    {
        Response.Write("this is a test");
    }
    protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton tRadio = (RadioButton)sender;
        var T = tRadio.ID.Split('_')[1];

        var statusBarID = "status_" + T;

        var StatusBar = tRadio.Parent.FindControl(statusBarID) as Panel;

        if (tRadio.Text == "Yes")
        {


            Dictionary<string,string> names = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            names.Add("1","a");
            names.Add("2", "a");
            names.Add("3", "a");
            names.Add("4", "a");
            names.Add("5", "a");
            names.Add("6", "a");
            names.Add("7", "a");
            names.Add("8", "a");
            names.Add("9", "a");

            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = names;


            ButtonField bOne = new ButtonField();
            bOne.CommandName = "buttonclicked";
            bOne.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
            bOne.Text = "Edit";
            gv.Columns.Add(bOne);
            gv.RowCommand += gv_RowCommand;

            gv.DataBind();
            StatusBar.Controls.Add(gv);




        }


    }
    void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I did a trivial implementation of your code, and it works as expected. VS2013, .NET 3.5, ASP.NET Web Forms Application. The only difference is I added my GridView to a form with runat=server, and you've added yours to some StatusBar somewhere? Try including the code for the StatusBar and I'll investigate further.

Comment: I am updating my code now to include the entire code block. This is all being created programatically.

Comment: Thank you for the full code. I can reproduce your problem now. I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm no ASP.NET Web Forms expert, but its probably something to do with the event handler no longer existing after the postback because the whole page is being dynamically created. Its also the reason why the GridView is disappearing when you click the button. This Stack Overflow post might be helpful [RowCommand not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144580/rowcommand-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

To fire the event, you need regenerate gridview when the postback event fired, please refer below. But still the code contains a problem to switch visible.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int T = 0; T <= 26; T++)
            {
                Label x = new Label();
                x.ID = T.ToString();
                x.Text = "orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla blandit id felis ac volutpat. Aenean tempor faucibus est, ac feugiat libero egestas sit amet. Aliquam";

                Label y = new Label();
                y.ID = "Title_" + T.ToString();
                y.Text = "Title " + T.ToString();

                RadioButton Radio1 = new RadioButton();
                Radio1.ID = "R_" + T.ToString();
                Radio1.Text = "Yes";
                Radio1.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
                Radio1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
                Radio1.AutoPostBack = true;

                RadioButton Radio2 = new RadioButton();
                Radio2.ID = "RX_" + T.ToString();
                Radio2.Text = "No";
                Radio2.GroupName = "Radio_" + T.ToString();
                Radio2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(this.CheckedChanged);
                Radio2.AutoPostBack = true;


                Panel StatusBar = new Panel();

                StatusBar.ID = "status_" + T.ToString();


                PlaceHolder pcl = new PlaceHolder();
                pcl.ID = "test_" + T.ToString();
                pcl.Controls.Add(y);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                pcl.Controls.Add(x);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                pcl.Controls.Add(Radio1);
                pcl.Controls.Add(Radio2);
                pcl.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>..."));
                form1.Controls.Add(pcl);
                form1.Controls.Add(StatusBar);

                ShowGridView(Radio1);
            }

            //form1.Controls.Add(new PlaceHolder { ID = "MyStatusBar" });
        }

        protected void test1()
        {
            Response.Write("this is a test");
        }

        protected void CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ShowGridView((RadioButton)sender);
        }

        void ShowGridView(RadioButton r)
        {
            RadioButton tRadio = r;
            var T = tRadio.ID.Split('_')[1];

            var statusBarID = "status_" + T;

            var StatusBar = tRadio.Parent.FindControl(statusBarID) as Panel;

            if (tRadio.Text == "Yes" && tRadio.Checked )
            {
                Dictionary<string, string> names = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                names.Add("1", "a");
                names.Add("2", "a");
                names.Add("3", "a");
                names.Add("4", "a");
                names.Add("5", "a");
                names.Add("6", "a");
                names.Add("7", "a");
                names.Add("8", "a");
                names.Add("9", "a");

                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = names;

                ButtonField bOne = new ButtonField();
                bOne.CommandName = "buttonclicked";
                bOne.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
                bOne.Text = "Edit";
                gv.Columns.Add(bOne);
                gv.RowCommand += gv_RowCommand;

                gv.DataBind();
                StatusBar.Controls.Add(gv);
            }
        }

        void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("buttonclicked"))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("fired");
            }
        }
```